Style the iFrame of a Looker Studio Community Visualization
I created a community visualization for Looker Studio.
The goal is to be able to create rectangles that I can style via css so I'm not limited by the Looker Studio styling options.
I defined a div inside my community visualization code and I'm able to style it via css by using the .css file that is going into the same directory and loaded via manifest.json.
However the visualization itself seems to be loaded into the dashboard via iFrame.
This creates issues whenever I try to style something that is "outside the box". So in my case: box shadow.
As the shadow is outside of the div element, it's not shown because it's outside of the iFrame containing my div.
However it seems like I can't style the iFrame itself as it is added by Looker Studio automatically and my .css file is not considered when the iFrame is loaded.
I tried to add stylings for several classes/IDs of the iFrame and the nested elements above and below. But I'm only able to style my div or the  tag surrounding it which is also inside the iFrame and thus makes the box shadow invisible as it's not overflowing the containing iFrame.
Is there any way to either make a box shadow go over the iFrame border or style the iFrame itself in Looker Studio community visualizations?

Does giving the iFrame padding help (e.g. after it has loaded, perhaps via JS)?

Might work, yes. Not sure how to do it though from the top of my head. Because I can't access the iFrame settings directly.
I now did a workaround where I added a div with some padding first and nested another div inside with width & height = calc(100% - 40px);
This gives me 20px on each side for the box shadow (probably I don't even need the outer div I guess).
Not sure about compatibility though.
